# TypeError: get_parent_class(): Argument #1 must be an object or a valid class name, string given in magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, schedule, free-gift

I get this error when I tap **"schedule new update"** button in a cart price rule page

[image]

you can see in the image below, I echo $className variable, which causes the error, it displays **"Mexbs\ApBase\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Action\Details\Staging"**, but there is no Staging file inside Details directory inside this module!

When I disable "**Mexbs**" module, everything works just fine
[image]

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Search in the module code where this class is called. As this is a Block, you will probably find it in a layout file in the adminhtml area. Also double check if you installed all the files